# State is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'am trying to fetch data from an API, then set it on my State and display that state in a table. The issue is that the render method is called first and causes my state to be undefined which causes this issue:

[image: issue]

The `console.log()`
[image: issue]
https://i.gyazo.com/642f8d6fe3481d2db9763091618e19de.png

```
state = {
      loading: true,
      data: [],
      customColumns: [],
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/lagbevakning/revision/subscriptions?id=' + (this.props.match.params.id)).then(response => {
      this.setState({
        data: response.data,
        loading: false
      })
    })

    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/lagbevakning/company?id=' + sessionStorage.getItem("id")).then(response2 => {
      this.setState({
        customColumns: response2.data
      })
    })
  }

  displayCustomColumn = (columnInput) => {
    if(columnInput === null) {
      return
    } else {
      return <Table.HeaderCell>{columnInput}</Table.HeaderCell>
    }
  }

  displayList = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <Table celled>
              <Table.Header>
                <Table.Row>
                  {this.displayCustomColumn(this.state.customColumns.customHeaderName1)}
                  {this.displayCustomColumn(this.state.customColumns.customHeaderName2)}
                </Table.Row>
              </Table.Header>

            {this.state.data.map((item, i) => (
              <Table.Body key={i}>
                <Table.Row>
                  <Table.Cell>{item}</Table.Cell>
                  <Table.Cell>{item}</Table.Cell>
                </Table.Row>
              </Table.Body>
            ))}
        </Table>
      </div>
   )}

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.loading
        ? <div><h1>LOADING...</h1></div>
        :
       <h2> Company  Name: {this.state.customColumns.companyName} <br/> 
            Revision Name: {this.state.data.name} <br/> 
            Revision ID:   {this.state.data.id}   </h2>
          }
      {this.displayList()}
    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this issue is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: this.state.data.map IS a function even when data is an empty array. It may not be a function when data is NOT an array at all, are you sure it's an array when you set it in componentDidMount? Try to log response.data into console before calling setState.

Comment: `this.state.data` is probably an object and objects don't have a `.map` function.

Comment: This could be the issue. it retrieves an object with multiple arrays
{[], [], []}
any suggestions on how i can work through this?

Comment: Can you show us the data that the object contains?

Comment: @ApplePearPerson
https://i.gyazo.com/e72710b6d787f24efdb64a0c71c60f1d.png

Comment: @ArastoSahbaei That is an array of objects not an object with multiple arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.loading
        ? <div><h1>LOADING...</h1></div>
        :
       <h2> Company  Name: {this.state.customColumns.companyName} <br/> 
            Revision Name: {this.state.data.name} <br/> 
            Revision ID:   {this.state.data.id}   </h2>
          }
      {this.displayList()}
    </div>
    )
  }
```

I think you are expecting data to be array so you can't access name and id from data state. Check structure of your response and set it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding the following :

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.loading
        ? <div><h1>LOADING...</h1></div>
        :
       <h2> Company  Name: {this.state.customColumns.companyName} <br/> 
            Revision Name: {this.state.data.name} <br/> 
            Revision ID:   {this.state.data.id}   </h2>
          }
       {this.state.data.length > 0 && this.displayList()}
    </div>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably try this.

```
 render() {
  if (this.state.loading) return <div><h1>LOADING...</h1></div>;
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.data && this.state.data.length &&
        <div>
          <h2> Company  Name: {this.state.customColumns.companyName} <br />
            Revision Name: {this.state.data.name} <br />
            Revision ID:   {this.state.data.id}   </h2>
          }
    {this.displayList()}
        </div>
    </div>
      )
    }
}
```

You can return immediately if `loading` is true. 
Below that you can check for `data` which is array of objects.

Comment: I stil recieve the typeError,
TypeError: _this.state.data.map is not a function